# Is there a better way to define this generator?

Tags: python, functional-programming, generator

Say I want to make a generator that returns a fixed number of users from a list, and if the number of users I want is greater than the length of the list, it just repeats the last user. I wrote a generator to do this below:

```
def gen_users(users, total):
    num_users = len(users)
    cur_user = 0
    while cur_user < total:
        if cur_user >= num_users:
            yield users[-1]
        else:
            yield users[cur_user]
        cur_user += 1
```

So if I had a list of users `users = ['one', 'two', 'three']` and I call `gen_users(users, 5)` I get back `one, two, three, three, three`.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this? Is using generators a valid approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> def gen_users(users, total):
...     # assert users and total > 0
...     for i, user in enumerate(itertools.islice(users, total)):
...         yield user
...     for _ in range(total - i - 1): # i -> last index
...         yield user
... 
>>> list(gen_users([1,2,3], 5))
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
>>> list(gen_users([1,2,3], 2))
[1, 2]
```

Alternatively you can use `users[:total]`, but it will create temporary sequence.

**UPDATE**

Slightly modified version of Hans Zauber's code:

```
>>> from itertools import islice, chain, repeat
>>> 
>>> def gen_users(users, total):
...     return islice(chain(users, repeat(users[-1])), total)
... 
>>> list(gen_users([1,2,3], 5))
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
>>> list(gen_users([1,2,3], 3))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(gen_users([1,2,3], 2))
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, I knew there had to be a better way to do this! Thanks.

Comment: If `total` is large, using `xrange` might be an improvement.

Comment: @HansZauber, I used `range` to make sure this code run both in Python 2.x, 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner:

```
import itertools
gen_users = lambda users, total: itertools.chain(itertools.islice(users, total), itertools.repeat(users[-1], total-len(users)))
```

Comment: Try `list(gen_users([1,2,3], 2))`.

Comment: Fixed, I forgot that case.

Comment: This answer is awesome too and equally valid. Thanks.